# Stones in a bag with Combinations

Tags: probability-theory, combinations

We have 25 stones in a bag. Some stones are black and the rest are white.
We select 2 stones in a row, one after the other, without repositioning.
If the probability of choosing two stones of the same color is equal to the probability of choosing two stones of different colors, find how many black stones are in the bag.

I figured out this is a combinations problems with C(25,2) different pairs of stones but I face difficulty in expressing the total of different pairs of the same color stones.
I would appreciate your guidance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are $x$ black stones, then there are $25-x$ white stones

So the total of different pairs of same color stones is

$$C(x,2)+C(25-x,2)$$

(you can also see that the total of different pairs of different color stones is $x(25-x)$)

Then by solving an quadratic equation you can find that the number of black stones is $10$ or $15$

Comment: I didn't get the same answer, I'm not sure why. I don't have any background in probability, so you're likely correct?

Comment: To whoever said (it might have been you) that I didn’t account for the case that both stones were white, that’s exactly where I went wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!!